# Transformar código de Visual Basic a C

Tags: c, vb.net, vba, vb6

Alguien me podría decir como es este código en `c` por favor

```
dim cadena as string 
dim indice as integer 
dim matriz(nn) as string * 1 

cadena = "as!%e&14%$92" 

for indice = 1 to len(trim(cadena)) 

matriz(indice) = mid$(cadena,indice,1) 

next
```

Comment: Hola Maria, bienvenida a [es.so]. Mira [ask] para aprender como hacer preguntas de mejor calidad. Has de mostrar lo que has intentado y no solo hacer una peticion. Cuando lo intentes, muestranos por que te falla o por que no sale como esperas.. Un saludo

Comment: ¿Has intentado traducirlo por cuenta propia al lenguaje C? De ser así, por favor edita la pregunta mostrandonos lo probado hasta el momento :D

Comment: ¿No entiendo lo de colocar las tres etiquetas? ¿Acaso el código expresado en `visual-basic` y que correctamente aplica a los tres lenguajes (vb.net, vba, vb6) tiene que tener las tres etiquetas? Disculpen la molestia.

Comment: @AgustinM. Parece más [tag:VB6] o [tag:VBA].

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es tener un array de los caracteres de una cadena:

```
 const string cadena = "as$%e&14%$92";
 var matriz = cadena.ToArray();
```

Si quieres que los elementos de `matriz` sean de tipo `string`:

```
 const string cadena = "as$%e&14%$92";
 var matriz = candena.Select(c=> c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Comment: No deberias responder ya que no muestra lo que ha intentado...

Comment: Aparte de lo dicho por @lois6b, ignoraba que _C_ tuviera el tipo `string`, ni la palabra reservada `var`. -1